# $\lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin({1\over x})$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $f(x)= x\sin({1\over x})\forall x>0$

Then evaluate

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin({1\over x})$

My approach: $\sin({1\over x})$ is periodic function and $x$ denotes its amplitude. So I thought $f$ is an unbounded function and hence will not have any feasible value for $x\to\infty$

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to understand why the limit of $x\cdot \sin (1/x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity is 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872275/i-need-to-understand-why-the-limit-of-x-cdot-sin-1-x-as-x-tends-to-infini)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice

$$ x \sin ( \frac{1}{x} ) = \frac{ \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) }{\frac{1}{x}} $$

Now, put $t = \frac{1}{x} $. Remember,

$$ \lim_{\alpha \to 0 } \frac{ \sin \alpha}{\alpha} = 1 $$